# Change Contiki MAC protocol to TDMA

Tags: contiki, cooja

I am working on the Cooja simulator. I create a network contains some sky motes. By default, CSMA is used as the mac layer of the motes but I want to change it to TDMA. TDMA MAC layer exists in Contiki 2.6 as `tdma_mac` but its removed in more recent versions of Contiki. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the recent versions in Contiki and in all versions of Contiki-NG there is a MAC protocol called TSCH.

To switch, add this to your application's Makefile:

```
MAKE_MAC = MAKE_MAC_TSCH
```

More information: https://github.com/contiki-ng/contiki-ng/wiki/Tutorial%3A-Switching-to-TSCH